# Not getting expected output when using bash OR '||'

Tags: linux, bash

I'm trying to write a simple bash script that checks the string if value is not "rpm" or "jar". But it seems to always be evaluating to true. I'm not sure what I'm missing.

```
#!/bin/bash
FILE_EXTENSION="rpm"

if [ "$FILE_EXTENSION" != "jar" ] || [ "$FILE_EXTENSION" != "rpm" ];
then
    echo "File type is NOT rpm or jar";
else
    echo "File type is rpm or jar";
fi

echo "Debug: FILE_EXTENSION value is $FILE_EXTENSION"
```

Running it on my local gets below output. It evaluates to true even though FILE_EXTENSION variable is set as "rpm"

```
$ ./check3.sh 
File type is NOT rpm or jar
Debug: FILE_EXTENSION value is rpm
$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confused about the logic. *a* OR *b* is true if *a* is true and you don't care about *b;* and it is true when *b* is true and then you don't need to care about the value of *a.*  The trivial fix for your problem is to switch to `&&` which is apparently what you wanted to check for.

I would in fact also prefer a `case` statement, as it is easier on the eyes (once you get past the syntax of the `case` statement itself, which can be unsettling if you are unfamiliar with it).

```
case $file_extension in
  rpm | jar) echo "File type is rpm or jar";;
  *) echo "File type is not rpm or jar";;
esac
```

See also [Correct Bash and shell script variable capitalization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673055/correct-bash-and-shell-script-variable-capitalization); I switched to lower case for this reason.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you're using `or` (`||`) instead of an `and` (`&&`). Currently you're checking if:

```
rpm != jar -> True
rpm != rpm -> False
True or False => True and you get "File type is NOT rpm or jar"
```